# Why is my RMI/IIOP java client getting CORBA MARSHAL exceptions on the Calendar class?

Tags: java, calendar, glassfish, rmi, corba

I have a Java RMI/IIOP client connecting to a SessionBean running in Glassfish 5.1.  I am able to look up the interface and invoke methods that return primitive types.  When I try to invoke a method that returns an application object, I get the following error.  It appears that the error occurs when the CORBA/RMI code is unmarshalling a standard Java Calendar object, more specifically the TimeZone within the Calendar object.  Calendar objects are Serializable, as is my app object that contains the Calendar instance.  Any ideas???

```
-- looking up interface [ejb/MPSInterface]--------------------------------------------------------

areYouAlive() returned:  true

isServerBusy() returned: false

issuing login request...
Login failed: Unable to establish user session:

javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
javax.ejb.EJBException: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at goesr.gs.mm.mps.msi.clientinterface._MPSInterface_Wrapper.processRequest(goesr/gs/mm/mps/msi/clientinterface/_MPSInterface_Wrapper.java)
    at goesr.gs.mm.mps.mpui.unit.CmdLineClient.login(CmdLineClient.java:47)
    at goesr.gs.mm.mps.mpui.unit.CmdLineClient.main(CmdLineClient.java:33)
Caused by: java.rmi.MarshalException: CORBA MARSHAL 1330446347 Maybe; nested exception is: 
    org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.javax.rmi.CORBA.Util.mapSystemException(Util.java:193)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:171)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.invoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.codegen.CodegenStubBase.invoke(CodegenStubBase.java:196)
    at goesr.gs.mm.mps.msi.clientinterface.__MPSInterface_Remote_DynamicStub.processRequest(goesr/gs/mm/mps/msi/clientinterface/__MPSInterface_Remote_DynamicStub.java)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: org.omg.CORBA.MARSHAL: WARNING: 00810011: Exception from readValue on ValueHandler in CDRInputStream  vmcid: OMG  minor code: 11 completed: Maybe
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.valuehandlerReadException(Unknown Source)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:788)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:883)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:701)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:694)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:684)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_abstract_interface(CDRInputObject.java:514)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectDelegate(IIOPInputStream.java:279)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride(IIOPInputStream.java:431)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:365)
    at java.util.Calendar$1.run(Calendar.java:3546)
    at java.util.Calendar$1.run(Calendar.java:3543)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.util.Calendar.readObject(Calendar.java:3542)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.invokeObjectReader(IIOPInputStream.java:1727)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1109)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:313)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:781)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:883)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:488)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2054)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2296)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1119)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:313)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:781)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:883)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:488)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObjectField(IIOPInputStream.java:2054)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2296)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1119)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:313)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:781)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.read_value(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:883)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputObject.read_value(CDRInputObject.java:488)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl$14.read(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.readResult(DynamicMethodMarshallerImpl.java:452)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.presentation.rmi.StubInvocationHandlerImpl.privateInvoke(StubInvocationHandlerImpl.java:161)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: Assigning instance of class java.lang.String to field java.util.TimeZone#ID
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2345)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputObject(IIOPInputStream.java:1119)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.simpleReadObject(IIOPInputStream.java:313)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValueInternal(ValueHandlerImpl.java:274)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.ValueHandlerImpl.readValue(ValueHandlerImpl.java:240)
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.encoding.CDRInputStream_1_0.readRMIIIOPValueType(CDRInputStream_1_0.java:781)
    ... 47 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.inputClassFields(IIOPInputStream.java:2322)
    ... 52 more
closing context...
Exiting
```

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use a class from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). They too are serializable.

Comment: RMI/IIOP doesn't use Java serialization, it uses, err, IIOP. I would need to see the code of the class concerned, and the remote interface, to help further.

Comment: Ole V.V. - not an option.  It's a legacy app being ported to Glassfish5.1 and Hibernate5.4.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: user207421 - ah, funny then that the stack trace includes an  entry for the Calendar.readObject() method.  Whether it's java serialization or IIOP, I still can't figure out why the server is able to marshal the object but the client cannot unmarshal the same object.  Thanks for the response.

Comment: And you'll also see that it has ultimately called `com.sun.corba.ee.impl.io.IIOPInputStream.readObjectOverride()` to actually write the data. Are client and server both running the same level of Java?

Comment: user207421 - yes, same jvm, same hibernate, gf-client.jar from the running glassfish instance.  I replaced the use of Calendar with Instant, removed the @Temporal annotation and viola - problem solved!